# SvnOperationFactory get method for svn "add" operation

Tags: java, svn, svnkit

I want to add and commit a file to my svn working copy using SVNKit. I try `SvnCommit` object reference but it does only allow to commit files which are already under version control:

```
SvnOperationFactory svnOperationFactory = new SvnOperationFactory();
svnOperationFactory.setAuthenticationManager(repo.getAuthenticationManager());
svnOperationFactory.setOptions(new DefaultSVNOptions());    

SvnCommit commit = svnOperationFactory.createCommit();
commit.addTarget(SvnTarget.fromFile(new File("D:/SVN/Temp/"+tmpPath)));
commit.run();
```

So I need a SVN operation from SVNKit which is equal to `add` method.

I know how to implement it with `SVNWCClient` but this approach is deprecated in SVNKit 1.7.2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SvnOperationFactory.createScheduleForAddition` is what you are looking for.

Comment: How do we add all new files in a specific folder?